# Навигация по синтаксическому дереву в emacs

Tags: emacs

Здравствуйте. Есть ли в emacs пакет, позволяющий перемещатся по буферу не в терминах "символ-вперед, предыдущая-строка и т.д", а где-то так - "следующее-выражение, список-аргументов"? Интересует поддержка js, python, html, css

Comment: Насколько мне известно (а эта область одна из направлений, в которые я частенько посматриваю), сейчас таких инструментов нет. Есть, конечно, `paredit` и его младший брат `parinfer`, но они предназначены только для лиспов. Есть `smartparens`, который покрывает много случаев, но руководствуется не AST.

Answer (score 3):

Есть очень удобные функции навигации

Создать мини буфер с функциями, классами и переменными. 
Смотри расширения для helm, ido, ivy

```
M-x imenu
```

Перемещение по функциям в текущем буфере

```
C-M-a
```

*Move to beginning of current or preceding defun (beginning-of-defun).*

```
C-M-e
```

*Move to end of current or following defun (end-of-defun).*

```
C-M-h
```

*Put region around whole current or following defun (mark-defun).*

Перейти к определению функции или переменной.
Работает с GNU global, ctags

```
M-.
```

Перейти к символу виденному в текущих активных буферах.

```
C-;
```

**Ссылки**

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JumpToDefinition
- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode
- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Defuns.html
- https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/master/README.md